# 88 ram 50 automatic not shifting right when moving

Tags: automatic-transmission

I changed the head and now it's not shifting as soon as it should winds up shifting into second at like 30 mph and I have to let off the accelerator
any ideas, I looked and did not see anything loose or off.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does it have a cable going from the transmission to the throttle linkage? If it does and it's either not connected or not adjusted right, your trans will shift wrong.